# My images are displaying incorrectly in IE 11 only

Tags: html, css

Hi HTML5 and CSS newbie here,

We had to create an interests page for our final project so I used 8 images stacked left to right contained in individual div containers with a caption that only appears when you hover over the photo.  It looks fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE all the photos are everywhere. Any help would be appreciated:

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="music.png" alt="Musician" id="musician">
            <p class="caption" id="musicP">I love all genres of music.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="movies.png" alt="Popcorn" id="popcorn">
            <p class="caption" id="movieP">Favorite romance comedy is Sleepless in Seattle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="reddit.png" alt="Reddit" id="reddit">
            <p class="caption" id="redditP">I love Reddit. I spend way too much time there.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="reading.png" alt="Books" id="books">
            <p class="caption">I only read fiction books.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="cooking.png" alt="Cooking" id="cooking">
            <p class="caption" id="cookingP">Favorite food is sushi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="videogames.png" alt="Video Games" id="games">
            <p class="caption">I'm playing Animal Crossing right now.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="football.png" alt="Football Game" id="football">
            <p class="caption">My favorite player is Peyton Manning!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interests">
            <img src="travel.png" alt="Globe" id="travel">
            <p class="caption">I'd like to visit Germany soon.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
/*Styles for the Interests Page*/

/*Floats all the photos to the left*/
.interests {
  float: left;
}

/*Styles for individual photos*/
#cooking{
  height: 180px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#books{
  width: 240px;
  height: 169px;
}
#games{
  height: 180px;
}

/*Photo Caption Styles*/
.caption{
  font-size: 70%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.interests:hover .caption{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cookingP{
  margin-left: 100px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a JSFiddle instead of pasting your HTML & CSS separately.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<img src="music.png" alt="Musician" id="musician">
```

close all your images to have a closing

```
<img src="music.png" alt="Musician" id="musician"/>
```

you are missing `/` in your image tags

Comment: That is perfectly valid HTML - only XHTML / XML require the closing slash for [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats. Use `display:table` on the `<section>` tag, `display:table-cell` on all the interest class divs, and wrap a div around the rows with the style `display:table-row`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp